# How to save a binary file submitted through an HTML form field?

Tags: c#, cgi, binaryfiles, forms

I need to add a function to an existing CGI application that is written in C# as a Windows Console app.  I need to add the ability for a few users to be able to submit a datafile for processing.  The datafiles can be either text/csv files or various binary files (.xls, .pdf).  I have a simple test HTML form set up using an  field for selecting/submitting the file.  That all works fine.  I can save a text file on the server with no problems.  But how do I save a binary file?  I'm sure it's easy to do but I've been unable to figure it out.

Below is some sample code that works for saving text files:

```
String formData = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
string boundary = string.Empty;
string[] cPairs = cType.Split(new string[] { "; " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string pair in cPairs) {
    //finds the 'boundary' text
    if (pair.Contains("boundary"))
        boundary = "--" + pair.Split('=')[1];
}

//splits on the 'boundary' to get individual form fields/sections
string[] sections = rawParams.Split(new string[] { boundary }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// parse each section
foreach (string section in sections) {
    string[] parts = section.Split(new string[] { "; ", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (parts[1].Equals("name=\"dFile\"")) { // 'dFile' is the form field-name for the datafile
        //below lines get the filename
        Regex regx = new Regex("filename=\"(.+)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match fPath = regx.Match(parts[2]);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fPath.Groups[1].Value);
        regx = new Regex("([-A-Z0-9_ .]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match fname = regx.Match(fi.Name);

        //below lines save the file contents to a text file; starts at index 4 of the 'parts' array
        if (fname.Groups[1].Success) {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fname.Groups[1].Value);
            for (int i = 4; i < parts.Length; i++) {
                tw.WriteLine(parts[i]);
            }
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
    else {
        // parse other non-file form fields
    }
}
```

The key part is the saving to a file.  How would I do that for a binary file?
   Dave

Comment: CGI application in C# ? What code do you have ?

Comment: @DaveKub What code do you have ?,C# Web or Win App...

Comment: I've added some sample code to the question.  The app is written as a console app.

Comment: Are you looking for the full file upload spec using multipart form data? In this case, you want to read this: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt and this http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt . Otherwise, I suggest you move onto a standard web listener: IIS, Cassini or the ASP.NET web stack (it's open source http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Changing to anything else isn't an option.  I'm stuck with adding to the existing CGI app that runs under Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to dump some data to a binary file, use something like:

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(fname.Groups[1].Value, SOME_SIZE, FileOptions.None))
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
...
//inside your loop
string s = parts[i];
formatter.Serialize(fs, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s));
```

Obviously `GetBytes()` using the correct encoding.

So your code would look like this:

```
String formData = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
string boundary = string.Empty;
string[] cPairs = cType.Split(new string[] { "; " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string pair in cPairs) {
//finds the 'boundary' text
if (pair.Contains("boundary"))
    boundary = "--" + pair.Split('=')[1];
}

//splits on the 'boundary' to get individual form fields/sections
string[] sections = rawParams.Split(new string[] { boundary }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// parse each section
foreach (string section in sections) {
string[] parts = section.Split(new string[] { "; ", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (parts[1].Equals("name=\"dFile\"")) { // 'dFile' is the form field-name for the datafile
    //below lines get the filename
    Regex regx = new Regex("filename=\"(.+)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match fPath = regx.Match(parts[2]);
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fPath.Groups[1].Value);
    regx = new Regex("([-A-Z0-9_ .]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match fname = regx.Match(fi.Name);

    FileStream fs = File.Create(fname.Groups[1].Value, SOME_SIZE, FileOptions.None))
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    //below lines save the file contents to a text file; starts at index 4 of the 'parts' array
    if (fname.Groups[1].Success) {
        for (int i = 4; i < parts.Length; i++) {
            string s = parts[i];
            formatter.Serialize(fs, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s));
        }
    }
}
else {
    // parse other non-file form fields
}
```

}

Comment: Tried that code and it creates a binary file, but it doesn't match the original.  I don't know what the 'correct' encoding is so I wrote a loop that goes through all of the `Encoding.GetEncodings()` and none of them produced a file that matched the original.

Comment: Tried a BinaryWriter instead of a BinaryFormatter?

Comment: Just tried a BinaryWriter; same result as the BinaryFormatter.  I'm testing with a zip file that contains a single text file.  Most of the encodings create a file that WinZip can't open at all; others create a file that WinZip can open and show the contents of, but can't extract.